# Apache-Camel route to generate and send PDF document in email

Tags: email, pdf, routes, apache-camel, document

I have a Apache-Camel route that should perform the following steps

1) generate pdf document from a list of objects
2) Send a email with the above pdf document as attachment.

I have a built a Java DSL Camel route that invokes the service component to retrieve the collection of objects, and generated a pdf document and the final step of sending the pdf as an email attachment.

This process is generating the email with PDF, but the generated PDF document seems to be corrupted and displays the error message "Acrobat Reader could not open because it is not a supported file type or file damaged".

I am using the code snippet as follows (not using PdfProducer)

```
exchange.getIn.addAttachment(fileID,new DataHandler(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(),"application/pdf"));
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Rename pdf to txt and open it with text editor. Maybe the content contains hints what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use a DataSource instead of the byte array.
For instance new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(bytes)), there are existing implementations called ByteArrayDatasource but i don't know if they are available within Apache Camel. You could implement your own DataSource.